# Can you run a thread in another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my programm, I want to run two seperate thread, which are initalized and launched in the main thread. This concept works fine for me, but when I now have to make a cooldown on one of the child threads while it is not paused it seems to still pause the thread;

Think of this as an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class testClass {
    static void grandchild();
    static void child();
public:
    void parent();
};

void testClass::grandchild() {
    //infinite loop of nothing;
    while (true);
}

void testClass::child() {
    //thread initalising and 
    std::thread grand(&testClass::grandchild);
    std::cout << "before join" << std::endl;
    grand.join();
    std::cout << "after join" << std::endl;
}

void testClass::parent() {
    std::thread child(&testClass::child);
    child.join();
}
int main() {
    testClass parentclass;
    parentclass.parent();
}
```

The output of this program now is

[image: http://puu.sh/ppTkR/e29221e1b8.png]

This also happens when I do this_thread::sleep_for and other functions which pause a thread. Can anyone explain me why this happens and what is possible for me to implement this properly or if this is even possible in C++?

Comment: When you write: *"I now have to make a cooldown on one of the child threads while it is not paused"*, what do you mean? What does *cooldown* mean in this context?

Comment: What do you expect? You are waiting while infinite loop finishes.

Comment: This example is meant to demonstrate the problem I have.
With cooldown I mean that I have to change a value in the child thread after a specific time. But I dont want the child thread to be pause while it does

Comment: As the example is currently written, the demonstrated problem is that you have an infinite loop.

Comment: You might want some kind of mesaging between threads, like `std::future` or atomic variables. In any case, do not call `.join` if you are not ready to wait unti other thread finishes.

Comment: So you want the child thread to start a grandchild thread that will wait for a certain amount of time and then change a value? But the child should keep running?

Answer (score 3):

`.join()` means "wait until that thread finishes". `parent` waits for `child` and `child` waits for `grandchild` and `grandchild` is stuck in an infinite loop, therefore nothing happens. You are effectively running single-threaded because you join with the threads you spawn.

You could not wait by using `.detach()` instead of `.join()`, but you should join all the threads before returning from `main`.

Comment: This actually helped me. The child thread in my program, not the example given, will not stop (unless any exception has been thrown and not caught right).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a modified program that uses the grandchild thread to wait for 3 seconds before changing a value.

The child thread keeps running.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

class testClass {
public:
    void grandchild();
    void child();
    void parent();
    std::atomic<int> value{0};
};

void testClass::grandchild()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    value = 5;
}

void testClass::child()
{
    //thread initalising and 
    std::cout << "Starting grandchild thread.\n";
    std::thread grand(&testClass::grandchild,this);
    //grand.detach(); // could detach so that a join() will not be required later
    for (int x{0}; x<5; ++x) {
        std::cout << x << '\t' << value << '\n';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    grand.join();
}

void testClass::parent()
{
    std::cout << "Starting child thread.\n";
    std::thread child(&testClass::child, this);
    child.join();
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting program\n";
    std::cout << "Starting parent thread.\n";
    testClass parentclass;
    parentclass.parent();
}
```

output:

```
Starting program
Starting parent thread.
Starting child thread.
Starting grandchild thread.
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       5
4       5
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65232d98e9215fa1)

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand The meaning of join() if  I'm right the constructor already launches the thread and join just waits for it. Am I right?

Comment: In this example, yes. `std::thread` is constructed and started (as opposed to constructing an empty thread). And yes, `join()` then waits for it to complete.

Comment: Are there examples where std::thread does not launch on constructing when you say _in this example_

Comment: @anon If you use the [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) the [thread object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) is constructed, but it does not represent a thread and there is nothing running.

Answer (score 2):

This program is behaving correctly.

1. It displays "before join".
2. It then waits until the infinite `while(1)` loop finishes.
3. After an infinite time, it displays "after join".

If you intend different behaviour, perhaps you could explain what that different behaviour is.

Comment: As you can see on my last comment "
 
This example is meant to demonstrate the problem I have. With cooldown I mean that I have to change a value in the child thread after a specific time. But I dont want the child thread to be pause while it does" I want to change a value for example after 5 seconds in the child thread while the child thread is not paused